# Perl and Multimap

Tags: perl

Is there way to implement a C++ multimap in perl?

Comment: Yes.  What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: As it stands, the question is *very* vague.

Comment: I don't agree that this question is particulary vague or imprecise, so long as you are familiar with a C++ multimap.  The hash of array refs is immediately what I thought of, and that was already posted.

Comment: @user275455 the reason it is vague is that it doesn't specify multimaps in C++, it just assumes we know which multimaps he or she is talking about.

Comment: It isn't reasonable to assume that a Perl reader will know what a C++ multimap is.  THerefore  question is unclear.

Comment: Even if the reader is familiar with C++, google shows about 6.5 million hits for "multimap -c++", so I feel quite safe in asserting that just plain "multimap" is not equivalent to "C++'s multimap".  In any case, I'll edit the question to specify that it's talking about the C++ multimap.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a [hash of arrays](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html#HASHES-OF-ARRAYS).

```
my %students = ( # keys are IDs, values are enrollments
    100023 => [qw(Geography Mining)],
    100058 => [qw(Geography Geology Woodcraft)],
);
```

Comment: just to be precise, you really want a hash of array refs

Answer (score 3):

If by multimap you mean the [C++ multimap](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/multimap/), then the answer is yes.  In Perl, a map corresponds to a hash.  The value associated with a given key in the hash can be a reference to a hash.  Perl also does not require you to use `->` after the first indexing operation, so instead of saying `$h{key1}->{key2}` you can just say `$h{key1}{key2}` which gives you a convincing illusion of a multi-dimensional hash.

Here is an example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my %h;

my $i;
for my $k (qw/one two three/) {
    for my $j (qw/a b c/) {
        $h{$k}{$j} = $i++;
    }
}

print "one b should be 1: $h{one}{b}\n",
    Dumper \%h;
```

Comment: A Perl hash actually corresponds to a C++ unordered_map not a map. Unlike Perl hashes and unordered_map, map and multimap are actually trees and preserve order (and thus only offer logarithmic time access instead of constant time).