# How can I retain all three values of a unique key in a hash using Perl?

Tags: perl, hash, unique-key

If in a `hash` I have one key and three values for same key. How can I retain all three values of that key?

E.g., America is my key and it has three values.

```
America = Clinton; America = Bush; America = Obama; 
if I use while loop `while(($a,$b) = % Country)
     { 
        print "$b\n"; 
     }
```

It gives me only the first value "Clinton". So, how to retain all the values for a given key inside while loop?? Please help me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3021021/14955

Comment: thanks thilo but here the key remains the same but the values are different ...So I want the output as America : Clinton ; Bush ; Obama  ..Please help me

Comment: In your case, the hash would be `{ America => [ 'Clinton', 'Bush', 'Obama' ]}`

Comment: yes but I am not understanding how to retrieve all the values for a unique key while loop. because when i use while (($a,$b) = % country) { print "$b\n";}  it prints only the first clinton as output.. can you help me modify the code to print all the three values in the while loop??

Comment: What does your data structure actually look like? The following things are unclear: what you're starting with, and what you hope to accomplish. Without those two things, it's very difficult (i.e., impossible) to help you.

Comment: It doesn't work that way. Your hash has  unique keys - so with multiple inserts, they overwrite.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example of using a hash of arrays:

```
my %presidents;

while (<DATA>) {
  chomp;
  my ($country, $president) = split /=/;
  push @{$presidents{$country}}, $president;
}

while (my ($country, $prez_ref) = each %presidents) {
  print "$country => @$prez_ref\n";  
}   

__DATA__
America=Clinton
America=Bush
America=Obama
```

Comment: Don't you need to initialize the empty arrayref for the first push to work? Or is this another case of Perl dwimmery?

Comment: That's pretty funny...  I don't know if this is what they call autovivification or not, but if not it's related.  I think I like dwimmery better, though.

Comment: Yes, autovivification is the word I was looking for (which is a form of dwimmery). But: Does it do that here? I know it does it for the hash key, but does it also create the arrayref on demand?

Comment: Yes, it works here.  It's one of those double-edged swords of Perl, but one I used to appreciate when I did a lot of Perl.

Comment: ok you have showed me to push the values into an array of hash but if there are more than one keys and all keys have multiple values say for eg India Modi                                                                                        India  Singh                                                                                           America  clinton                                                                                        America bush ..then how to look for both values for both keys?? Please help

Comment: That would be a separate question,  and best asked explicitly. Cross reference this answer and ask it.

Comment: Julie -- when you do pose that question, be sure to list your input and your expected output.  I think that will help clarify the question a lot.

Comment: Hambone -- my i/p is $a = 1 \n $b = 2 \n $b = 3 \n $c = 4 \n $c = 5 now I used while(($a,$b) = each %hash){ print "$b\n";} but this is giving me output as 1\n3\n5 that is only one value is printed for each key but i want the o/p as 1\n2;3;4\n5 that is all the values should be printed for each key. but how can i do that inside a while loop??

Comment: Julie -- can you post the full code for this?  I think it has to do with the way you are pushing those values onto the hash.  My guess is you're doing something like `$hash{$a} = $b` which will overwrite the prior value, when what you want to do is `$hash{$a}{$b} = 1` (HOH) or `push @${hash{$a}}, $b` (AOH).  If it's related to this same issue, post as much relevant code as you can below your original post (above) and comment so we know to look at this thread again

Answer (score 2):

```
my %country = (
    'America' => ['Clinton', 'Bush', 'Obama'],
    'UK'      => 'Maggie'
    );

while (($a, $b) = each %country) {
    print ref $b ? join ", ", @$b : $b, "\n";
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't do that. Having one key giving scalar, and another giving a reference means you are being inconsistent. Just push to all of them, and then you always have to dereference.

Comment: I admit I've never done it, in these situations I've always been type faithful (what a laughable concept for perl) and created an array of hash, but I'm not hugely offended by it.